# Create a Makefile to compile all .c files in a folder/subfolder and ship the binaries elsewhere

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am currently studying K&R and I would like to create a Makefile in order to automate the compiling process.

I have a directory structured as follows :

```
k-r/
    chapter-1/
        exe/
        1-1/
            program1.c
            program2.c
            ...
        1-2/
            program3.c
            program4.c
            ...
    ch1.c
    ch1.h
```

Most of the programs are self-contained but some require functions which are defined in k-r/chapter-1/ch1.c and k-r/chapter-1/ch1.h.

I would like to compile all the programs in k-r/chapter-1/1-1, k-r/chapter-1/1-2 and so on, and ship the executable binaries to k-r/chapter-1/exe.

Below is what I have so far and it works, but I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do it, for example without having to list the filenames ?

```
CC := clang
CFLAGS := -Wall
LIB := ../ch1.c
BIN := ../exe/

.PHONY: all clean 1-1 1-2

all: 1-1 1-2

1-1:
    cd 1-1 && \
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) program1.c -o $(BIN)program1.exe && \
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) program2.c -o $(BIN)program2.exe && \

1-2:
    cd 1-2 && \
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) program3.c $(LIB) -o $(BIN)program3.exe && \
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) program4.c $(LIB) -o $(BIN)program4.exe && \

clean:
    rm exe/*
```

Comment: Have you tried to write such a makefile? How close have you come to a solution?

Comment: Yes, I think I'm not far from the solution, I've updated the OP accordingly.

Comment: Maybe add the "outer code" to a library ... and then link that library with the "inner code"

Comment: You are using a lot of vague language that makes your question very difficult to understand. What binary files do you want to produce? Is `bin/program1.o` one of them?

Comment: I would like to produce only the final, executable files in the bin folder, with the following format `bin/program1`.

Comment: @Beta I found a solution but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it. I have updated the OP accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that by "efficient" you mean "more generic/automated". Here is the most "efficient" solution I could think of:

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall
BIN_DIR := exe
SRC_DIRS := $(wildcard *-*)

.PHONY: all clean $(SRC_DIRS)
all: $(SRC_DIRS)

clean:
    del /s /q $(BIN_DIR)\*

define SETUP_TARGETS
$(1): $$(patsubst $(1)/%.c,$(BIN_DIR)/%.exe,$$(wildcard $(1)/*.c))
$(BIN_DIR)/%.exe: $(1)/%.c $$(wildcard *.c)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $$(addprefix -I ,$$(patsubst %/,%,$$(dir $$^))) $$^ -o $$@
endef

$(foreach target,$(SRC_DIRS),$(eval $(call SETUP_TARGETS,$(target))))
```

Observations about the makefile:

- Since you are using the file extension `.exe`, I am assuming that you are running GNU Make on MS-Windows. Hence, I used Command Prompt syntax and `.exe` extension.
- You have to put the makefile in the root directory of the chapter (`chapter-1/` in this case).
- When you copy the code to your makefile, please pay attention to the indented parts (recipe of each rule). Each command line must start with a `TAB` character, not spaces.
- I am assuming the directory `exe/` already exists and always will be there.
- The makefile will detect every subdirectory that matches the pattern `*-*` (e.g. 1-1, 1-2, ...) and will create a target for each one.
- The command line `make target` (target is a subdirectory, e.g. 1-1, 1-2, ...) will create one executable in `exe/` for each source file in the target subdirectory. I am assuming that each source file has a function `main()`.
- Each target build will also include every source file `*.c` from the root directory (`ch1.c` in this case). I am assuming that these sources do not contain a function `main()`.
- The files involved in the builds do not have to be named in any particular way. All files will be detected.
- The include paths used in the compilations are the same directories that contain the sources involved, which are the target subdirectory and the root directory. Hence, you can `#include` header files from them to your programs.
- The command lines `make` and `make all` will build all the targets.
- The command line `make clean` will delete every file in `exe/`.
- This makefile was created to minimize build operations so that only executables that are out of date with respect to one of their dependent sources will be built. If you try to rebuild a target without modifying any source, you are going to get a warning like `make: Nothing to be done for '1-1'`.
- You can use this makefile for other chapters as well, as long as they have the same directory structure.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I am using macOS but I'll have no problem translating Command Prompt syntax into shell syntax.